# How do I create a gridview with an empty column to allow user to enter a value which will then be used with the rest of the columns to update a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

How do I create a gridview with an empty column to allow user to enter a value which will then be used with the rest of the columns to update a table. I was hoping to allow user to go down a gridview change a number of values and upon button push have the new table displayed to review changes before submitting to a database. The gridview is dynamically bound from an ilist which makes it difficult as the page lifecycle disables me pulling the items out using .findcontrol. And Neither can I use viewstate("newtable") = ilist method as this will not account for the editable field. Help!!!

J

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your question is not clear if you put your code sample it will be more. if you work with entity framework for database op., datagridview already allow updates. yourentityobject.SaveChanges() is enough.